# Escaping one single quote and one double quote from csv to SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, escaping

I am trying to generate a csv file with which I will eventually seed a postgres db (doing it this way because of the size - millions of records). I have seen examples of how to escape apostrophes or double quotes in csv and SQL, but not singles of both together in the same string. I.e., height represented as `5'11"`. This has caused a lot of headache, any help appreciated.

What I have already tried:

```
'5''11"'
"5'11"" 
"5'11"""
'5\'11\"'
"5\'11\""
```

Comment: I think probably this has as much or more to do with how you are using `COPY` and/or `\copy` to import into the database. So what are you doing on that end?

Comment: It is a good practice to stick to standards. Although there is no strict standard for CSV, [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) is widely accepted as one. I suggest that you stick to it as is the answer of @LaurenzAlbe.

Answer (score 0):

There is always only one quoting character, by default `"`. Then you don't have to escape any other character like `'`.

So your string will become

```
"5'11"""
```